# Sending credential to a login web page

Tags: javascript, c#, jsp, batch-file, web

Is there a way to send username and password to a url of a login web page? 
For example, if the login web page contains 2 textboxes : user name and password and a login button, is there a way to send to the url the credential in order to go directly to the next page coming after the login?

The url for the login page looks like:

> http://[ip address]/jsp/login.xhtml

I tried to send the username and passord as following:

> http://[username:password]/[ip address]/jsp/login.xhtml
>
> http://[ip address]/jsp/login.xhtml?[username:password]

If there is a way to do it by sending the command through a batch file?
If it can be done using c# or javascript it is also fine.

Comment: this depends on how the page processes the credentials. Most likely, this wil be through a 'post'. If so, you should look into how to send your credentials directly to the script verifying your credentials.

Comment: I looked at the view source and I saw:
method="post" action="/jsp/login.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: this means the data gets sent to 'http://[ip address]/jsp/login.xhtml' in 'post', now you need to find out how you want to do it. I suggest using javascript (more info on how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit), This can be run by a plugin Like 'Custom Javascript for Websites' plugin for chrome.

Comment: @ Anthony Dekimpe, I liked the javascript solution however I am not really clear how to write it. Could you add it as answer and help a little more with this solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option is Javascript. It can easily run from a plugin of your browser.
(I'm using 'Custom Javascript for Websites', a chrome plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija)

Firstly you navigate to the login page and check the source code for the following ID's:
 - Username-inputbox
 - Password-inputbox
 - Submit button

Knowing these things, we can add this to our plugin: (Fill in the id's at the right places)

```
// First we check if we're on the right page
if (window.location.href == "URL")
{
    // Find the ID's of the corresponding inputs
    document.getElementById("username").value = "user0";
    document.getElementById("password").value = "user0scode";

    // Then click the submit button, just as we do
    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").click();
}
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Is it possible to inject this piece of code from a batch file or a C# directly to the cjs extension for the requested url?

Comment: You can accomplish this with the webbrowser control in Windows.Forms in C#:

Create a webbrowser ('wb') and navigate to the page,
Then catch the event 'OnDocumentCompleted', and use the build-in functions:

`wb.Navigate("URL");`
`wb.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(wb_DocumentCompleted);`


Then put this in the DocumentCompleted handler:
`wb.Document.GetElementById("username").InnerText = "user0";
wb.Document.GetElementById("password").InnerText = "user0scode";

wb.Document.GetElementById("submitButton").InvokeMember("click");`

Answer (score 1):

There is free tool called Fiddler. It monitors/debugs all the traffic on your machine i.e. using browsers or any other medium. You can try capturing the action/request behind the login button using Fiddler, and then mutate the same action/request and you will be able to change the username/password for that action/request.

Download from [here](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), and read [this](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Modify-Traffic/Tasks/CustomizeRequest).

Comment: Interesting but I do not have the possibility to install such tools. Thanks

Comment: Why is that? Can you shed some more light on it?

Comment: You just need to use it once for capturing the request, and later you can write your own .Net/Java app to make those requests.

Comment: If company allows you then you can follow my last comment.

Comment: No problem, mate.
If you want to do this without that tool, then you may try inspecting the page. I can give it a try if it is okay for you to share the URL.

Comment: Sorry, not possible to share it and also it is an intranet url